# Store an entity in a hidden field of a parent page and access the hidden field entity value in child page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, web, master-pages

In our project, there is an requirement to avoid session and view state. In parent page, there is a filter option which is done by an search criteria entity. I have to keep the search criteria entity value of the parent page and pass it to the popup(Child page).

Comment: What did you tried so far? Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value as a query string.